# How to toggle individual row at a time in vue for rows generated from an array?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a table of values ... I need to create an edit-in-place form experience for each row in that table. As a user when I hit the “edit” button..that ONE row will change into a form I can then edit and press the “submit” button for that one row. How can I make that happen?

How can I make this happen? Also, I'm a bit new to Vue. So if you can provide and a working example in your response that would be fantastic.

Thank you for your time.

Here is what I have so far....

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" >
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Duration</th>
        <th scope="col">Freq</th>
        <th scope="col">Dosage</th>
        <th scope="col">Notes</th>
        <th scope="col">Actions</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr v-for="med in catMedications">
       <td><form :id="'form'+med.id" @submit.prevent="validateMedicationsBeforeSubmit(med.id, med.name, 'edit')"><fg-input v-if="!showRow" name="id" :value="med.id"></fg-input></form><span v-if="showRow">{{med.id}}</span></td>
       <td><fg-input v-if="!showRow" :form="'form'+med.id" name="name" v-validate="'required'" v-model="name" type="text" :placeholder="med.name" :error="getError('requiredText')"></fg-input><span v-if="showRow">{{med.name}}</span></td>
       <td><fg-input v-if="!showRow" :form="'form'+med.id" name="duration" v-validate="'required'" v-model="duration" type="text" :placeholder="med.duration" :error="getError('duration')"></fg-input><span v-if="showRow">{{med.duration}}</span></td>
       <td><fg-input v-if="!showRow" :form="'form'+med.id" name="frequency" v-validate="'required|integer'" v-model="frequency" :error="getError('frequency')" type="text" :placeholder="med.frequency"></fg-input><span v-if="showRow">{{med.frequency}}</span></td>
       <td><fg-input v-if="!showRow" :form="'form'+med.id" name="dosage" v-validate="'required|integer'" v-model="dosage" :error="getError('dosage')" type="text" :placeholder="med.dosage"></fg-input><span v-if="showRow">{{med.dosage}}</span></td>
       <td><fg-input v-if="!showRow" :form="'form'+med.id" name="notes" v-model="notes" :error="getError('notes')" type="textarea" :placeholder="med.notes"></fg-input><span v-if="showRow">{{med.notes}}</span></td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-info" @click='showRow = !showRow'><span v-if="showRow">Edit</span><span v-if="!showRow">Cancel</span></button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" v-if="!showRow">Submit</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


data () {
   return{
      showRow: true,
   }
}
```

ANS: Based off BERT'S codepen...

```
<div id="app">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" >
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="med in catMedications">
        <td><input v-if="!med.showRow" name="id" v-model="med.id"/><span v-if="med.showRow">{{med.id}}</span></td>
        <td><input v-if="!med.showRow" :form="'form'+med.id" name="name" v-model="med.name" /><span v-if="med.showRow">{{med.name}}</span></td>

        <td>
          <button class="btn btn-sm btn-info" @click='med.showRow = !med.showRow'><span v-if="med.showRow">Edit</span><span v-if="!med.showRow">Cancel</span></button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" v-if="!med.showRow">Submit</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data:{
    catMedications:[
      {id: 1, name: "Bob", showRow: true},
      {id: 2, name: "Mary", showRow: true},
    ]
  }
})
```

NOTE: my catMedications array is coming from an external back-end database so I had to change the model for that table and simply add a "showRow: true" boolean feild.

Now I can select each individual row.

(working to see if posting to form will work as expected...I'll update this post accordingly in a moment)

Comment: Variants of this question are asked all the time in the Vue tag. If someone has a better dup I'll mark this as a dup of that. For now, this one should do. Basically, you need a state for each item. This is typically handled by adding the state to the item. Alternatively you could create a structure that stores the states of items and use that.

Comment: Bert...thank you for your response. I have been searching S.O. for 2 days. I would be excited to see an EXACT representation of what I'm asking already answered. Also, can you please tell me what you mean by "adding the state to the item". I've read the post you are referring to...I'm not understanding how that can be applied here in this case. I'm a bit new to vue so please be kind. A working example would be fantastic. Can you please point me to one if you know of one? Thank you.

Comment: Here is an example of just toggling the rows. The rest of the stuff you have going on (the stuff with your form) you probably need to ask another question. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/MXNvqw?editors=1010

Comment: I'll take a look...I'll also update my form (I simplified it for this post...as the original version looks pretty "busy")

Comment: Since the catMedications array is coming from an external database.  I would have to add a "showRow: true" field to the model in the back-end. LOL I would never have figured that out.

Comment: Thank YOU Bert ... that codepen was very helpful!